# How do I install an equalizer in Rhythmbox?

Tags: rhythmbox, 12.04, plugins, equalizer

Previous I have never used rhythmbox by default because it seemed to be lacking in features to me. Just my personal opinion.

With rhythmbox back in 12.04 will ubuntu give it some attention to give it some usability one thing that was majorly missing on my last use of rhythmbox was an equalizer which is the most basic of requirements for an audio player let alone a preamp.

I have searched and found that on the rhythmbox website the plugin is available but in the plugins menu of rhythmbox it is not there.

I searched google and there are many guides from 2009 trying to install the equalizer. there is nothing recent and one would assume this would be a default plugin, there is no point after all searching for cover art if your music doesn't sound right.

How can I easily install the equalizer in 12.04?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Rhythmbox](http://rhythmbox.org/) is not a canonical product so I don't think canonical can do anything about it. If you need a feature may be you can request feature to rhythmbox developers. If you are talking about [third party plugin](http://live.gnome.org/RhythmboxPlugins/ThirdParty) called  [10 Band Equalizer](https://github.com/luqmana/rhythmbox-plugins/tree/master/equalizer).

What you can do is create a folder called `plugins` in `$HOME/.local/share/rhythmbox` and download the [plugin](https://github.com/luqmana/rhythmbox-plugins/tarball/master) and extract the equalizer folder in the `plugins` folder you created.

OR

If you know how to use `git` and have `git` installed. Just goto `$HOME/.local/share/rhythmbox` and do:

`git clone https://github.com/luqmana/rhythmbox-plugins.git plugins`

and then you can update your plugin with `git pull` command from `plugins` directory

Then enable the plugin from rhythmbox.

[image]

It can also be installed via a PPA as described in the linked question.

---

Linked Question:
 - [How do I install third-party rhythmbox plugins?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147942/how-do-i-install-third-party-rhythmbox-plugins/147943#147943)

Comment: The PPA referred to is awesome...definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 27):

As of 13/06/2012, this [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~fossfreedom/+archive/rhythmbox-plugins) seems to contain the latest version of the "10 Band Equalizer" (rhythmbox-plugin-equalizer) and its working great for me (on 12.04 and 14.04-64bit).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fossfreedom/rhythmbox-plugins
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rhythmbox-plugin-equalizer
```